# JOIN of 3 tables and SUM ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables:

```
Product:
+----------------------------------------+
| ID_product | name_product |   Amount   |
+----------------------------------------+
|     0      |    Door      |    450     |
+----------------------------------------+
|     1      |    Fence     |    1500    |
+----------------------------------------+

Operation:
+----------------------------------------+
| ID_operation | name_operation |  cost  |
+----------------------------------------+
|      0       |     Repair     |   250  |
+----------------------------------------+
|      1       |     Build      |   320  |
+----------------------------------------+

Process:
+----------------------------------------+
|    ID_product   |    ID_operation      |
+----------------------------------------+
|       0         |          0           |
+----------------------------------------+
|       0         |          1           |
+----------------------------------------+
|       1         |          0           |
+----------------------------------------+
|       1         |          1           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

> And need to calculate the sum of costs for each product like this:

```
    Result table:
   +-----------------------------------+
   |  name_product  |    TOTAL_COSTS   |
   +-----------------------------------+
   |      Door      |   570 (250+320)  |
   +-----------------------------------+
   |      Fence     |        570       |
   +-----------------------------------+
```

But i don't have any idea how. I think I need some JOINS like below but I don't know how to handle the sum.

```
SELECT name_product, operation.cost
FROM product
JOIN process ON product.ID_product = process.ID_product
JOIN operation ON operation.ID_operation = process.ID_operation
ORDER BY product.ID_product;
```

Comment: Why does Fence `TOTAL_COSTS` equal to 370?

Comment: Sorry, i mean 570. I'll edit ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Your `JOIN`s are OK, you just need to add a `GROUP BY` clause with aggregate function `SUM`.

```
SELECT product.name_product, SUM(operation.cost) total_costs
FROM product
JOIN process ON product.ID_product = process.ID_product
JOIN operation ON operation.ID_operation = process.ID_operation
GROUP BY product.ID_product, product.name_product
ORDER BY product.ID_product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below `Query`

```
SELECT P.NAME_PRODUCT,SUM(O.COST)COST
FROM PROCESS PR,PRODUCT P,OPERATION O
WHERE PR.ID_PRODUCT=P.ID_PRODUCT
AND PR.ID_OPERATION=O.ID_OPERATION
GROUP BY P.NAME_PRODUCT;
```